# Difference between ARM SKU Name and SKU Name in Azure EA

Tags: azure, sku

I have been working with the Azure Consumption APIs and I noticed that these two APIs return very similar variables with different names:

The [reservationcharges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/billing/enterprise/billing-enterprise-api-reserved-instance-charges#response) endpoint defines `armSkuName` as:

```
+-----------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
|    Property Name      |  Type   |                   Description                |
+-----------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
| armSkuName            | string  | String representing the purchased resource.  |
+-----------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
```

The [reservationsummaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/billing/enterprise/billing-enterprise-api-reserved-instance-usage#response-1) endpoint defines `skuName` as:

```
+-----------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
|    Property Name      |  Type   |                   Description                |
+-----------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
| skuName               | string  | String representing the purchased resource.  |
+-----------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
```

I know that ARM SKU means Azure Resource Manager Stock Keeping Unit and SKU means Stock Keeping Unit, but I'm unclear on the distinction between the two?

Is the armSkuName specifically naming it as an [ARM SKU as opposed to a classic ASM SKU](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/igorpag/2015/11/04/azure-vm-resizing-and-sku-change-in-asm-and-arm/)? Does skuName encompass both?

Are there any Azure docs that explain the distinction between the two? Is there a distinction to make?